# Mathematically representing combinations with integers uniquely?

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

Say I want to pick up $k$ amongst $n$ with respect to order. I am thinking about splitting it into two separate problems.

```
1. First selection of the k elements among the n.
2. Internal permutations amongst the k elements.
```

This question is about how to represent selection for the first part. I am thinking about building a number to encode placement. Say I take a number from $\{1,n\cdots(n-k)\}$:

```
0. Start with i=n
1. Output modulo i as first position
2. Divide by i.
3. Reduce i by 1.
4. If i >= k repeat from 1 otherwise be done
```

But this won't be maximally compact as order affects which number will be encoded and that's what I plan to solve in problem 2 separately.

How about a pigeonhole approach instead? Instead take number from $\{1,(n-k+1)^k\}$. As we are sure that at least one selection must occur in the first $n-k+1$ That's a smaller set of integers to map to, and it will sure be sufficient as we can do induction after each selection - hopping over that index and pretending it is the next. But will it give a unique or compact code? If not, does there exist some other way which is both unique and so that no 2 numbers in the set encode for the same configuration?

---

**EDIT**: I tried the approach by Austin combined with a [bitwise Hamming Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) calculator and a loop

```
1. Start with a binary number k least significant bits set.
2. Count up 1 until next hamming distance == k. Output that number.
3. When done with that comb put the number back into 2 and wait for next number.
```

The numbers we have to loop through will be $2^n - 2^k$ in order to get the $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}$ combinations.
[image]

As modern CPUs have "popcount" instructions built into hardware (Streaming SIMD Extensions V4, I think) executing in just 1 or 2 cycles this will probably get quite efficient anyway. On my machine (3.4 GHz or $3.4\cdot 10^{9}$ cycles per second) I can with some optimization effort get it to check all combination of 15 among 31 in about $2.4$ seconds. $$\frac{2.4\cdot 3.4\cdot 10^9} { 2^{31}} \approx 3.8 \text{   instructions per candidate}$$ and $$\frac{2.4\cdot 3.4\cdot 10^9}{\frac{31!}{(31-15)!15!}} \approx 27.2 \text{            instructions per combination}$$Probably there do exist smarter ways to go about than to just increment 1 at a time too.

---

**EDIT 2**

Regarding better increments: one safe increment to make is to add the binary munber by as much as it's lowest significant bit as adding with anything less will ensure that the next number has a sum of ones larger than the current sum. If we switch to this new strategy we get efficiency plots like these:
[image]
And on modern CPUs they are oftentimes only 1-3 times slower than exact logical bit-twiddling methods. But keep in mind that much of this gain for our method is due to the existance of popcnt and other instructions on the modern CPUs ( I think it is SSE 4 ).

Comment: You seem to be paying meticulous detail to efficiency. Do you have a particular application in mind? I'm just curious.

Comment: I sometimes just get really into something when I get curious about it. I should maybe move all the performance considerations somewhere else as it actually is not part of the original question formulation. Like a low level programming forum or something.

Comment: You may as well leave the performance details. I don't think they detract from the discussion.

Comment: I might be misreading the question, but the  [combinatorial number system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_number_system) seems to be what you want here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take your question to be about representing a selection of elements from $\{1, 2, \dots, n\}$ without regard to order. A common way is to use an $n$-digit binary string whose $i$th digit (reading right to left) is $1$ if and only if the element $i$ belongs to the selection. Each such string corresponds to a unique integer.

For example, suppose I make the selection $\{1, 3, 4\}$ from the set $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$. I could represent the selection with the binary string $01101$, which corresponds to the integer $13$.

Comment: Yes this is nice in the sense that no two different binary strings will encode the same selection. But I wonder how easy they are to enumerate. I didn't mention in the question but I would also like to be able to "cycle through" selections.

Comment: @mathreadler I've updated the scheme to "cycle through" the sets more naturally. You can start with 0, which corresponds to the empty set. Next is 1, which corresponds to the set $\{1\}$. Next is 2 (binary $10$), which corresponds to the set $\{2\}$, and so forth.

Comment: I think this will work relatively nicely for generating combinations if I start with $00111$, loops add 1 until hamming weight is restored to 3, output the new number and iterate. There even seem to be CPU instructions in hardware for hamming weight these days.