# Find a six digit integer

Tags: divisibility, integers

Find an integer with six different digits such that the six digit integer is divisible by each of its digits.

For example, find ABCDEF such that A, B, C, D, E and F all can divide the number ABCDEF.

Show your answer along with mathematical reasoning.

Comment: How about 111111

Comment: Do all digits have to be unique?

Comment: ^Yes, left out that part.

Answer (score 5):

The number $861432$ will work.  I guess $123864$ looks nicer.

Comment: Lucky guess and check?

Comment: I'm guessing software

Comment: Well, it was clear we could not use $5$, so the only thing to arrange was sum of digits divisible by $3$ and divisibility by $8$. There are lots of variants.

Answer (score 3):

$4\\
24\\
624\\
3624\\
183624$

2,4,8 are good to work with, because once you find three digits at the end, you can put whatever you want in the front.

3,6,9 are good to work with too, because if you find something that divides by 3 or 9, you can shuffle the digits and it still divides by 3 (or 9).

and 1 is just a no-brainer

Answer (score 3):

Result of exhaustive search with software:

```
123648, 123864, 123984, 124368, 126384, 129384, 132648, 132864, 
132984, 134928, 136248, 136824, 138264, 138624, 139248, 139824, 
142368, 143928, 146328, 146832, 148392, 148632, 149328, 149832, 
162384, 163248, 163824, 164328, 164832, 167328, 167832, 168432, 
172368, 183264, 183624, 184392, 184632, 186432, 189432, 192384, 
193248, 193824, 194328, 194832, 198432, 213648, 213864, 213984, 
214368, 216384, 218736, 219384, 231648, 231864, 231984, 234168, 
234816, 236184, 238416, 239184, 241368, 243168, 243768, 243816, 
247968, 248136, 248976, 261384, 263184, 273168, 281736, 283416, 
284136, 291384, 293184, 297864, 312648, 312864, 312984, 314928, 
316248, 316824, 318264, 318624, 319248, 319824, 321648, 321864, 
321984, 324168, 324816, 326184, 328416, 329184, 341928, 342168, 
342816, 346128, 348192, 348216, 348912, 349128, 361248, 361824, 
361872, 362184, 364128, 364728, 367248, 376824, 381264, 381624, 
382416, 384192, 384216, 384912, 391248, 391824, 392184, 394128, 
412368, 413928, 416328, 416832, 418392, 418632, 419328, 419832, 
421368, 423168, 423816, 427896, 428136, 428736, 431928, 432168, 
432768, 432816, 436128, 438192, 438216, 438912, 439128, 461328, 
461832, 463128, 468312, 469728, 478296, 478632, 481392, 481632, 
482136, 483192, 483216, 483672, 483912, 486312, 489312, 491328, 
491832, 493128, 498312, 612384, 613248, 613824, 613872, 614328, 
614832, 618432, 621384, 623184, 623784, 627984, 631248, 631824, 
632184, 634128, 634872, 641328, 641832, 643128, 648312, 671328, 
671832, 681432, 684312, 689472, 732648, 732816, 742896, 746928, 
762384, 768432, 783216, 789264, 796824, 813264, 813624, 814392, 
814632, 816432, 819432, 823416, 824136, 824376, 831264, 831624, 
832416, 834192, 834216, 834912, 836472, 841392, 841632, 842136, 
843192, 843216, 843912, 846312, 849312, 861432, 864312, 873264, 
891432, 894312, 897624, 912384, 913248, 913824, 914328, 914832, 
918432, 921384, 923184, 927864, 931248, 931824, 932184, 934128, 
941328, 941832, 943128, 948312, 976248, 978264, 981432, 984312
```

There are more solutions, $248$, than I initially expected.

Mathematica code:

```
check[a_, b_, c_, d_, e_, f_] := Module[{
    n
  },
  n = f + 10 (e + 10 (d + 10 (c + 10 (b + 10 a))));
  {
    And[
      (* all inputs digits? *)
      0 < a < 10, 0 < b < 10, 0 < c < 10, 0 < d < 10, 0 < e < 10, 0 < f < 10,
      a \[Element] Integers, b \[Element] Integers, 
      c \[Element] Integers, d \[Element] Integers, 
      e \[Element] Integers, f \[Element] Integers, 
      (* all inputs distinct?  *)
      a != b, a != c, a != d, a != e, a != f,
      b != c, b != d, b != e, b != f,
      c != d, c != e, c != f,
      d != e, d != f,
      e != f,
      (* the long number is divisible by each digit? *)
      n/a \[Element] Integers,
      n/b \[Element] Integers,
      n/c \[Element] Integers,
      n/d \[Element] Integers,
      n/e \[Element] Integers,
      n/f \[Element] Integers
    ], 
    n
  }
]

Select[Flatten[
  Outer[check, Range[1, 9], Range[1, 9], Range[1, 9], Range[1, 9],  Range[1, 9], Range[1, 9]
  ],
  5], #[[1]] &
][[All, 2]]
```

The last command makes every possible 6-tuple of an integers in $[1,9]$ and passes those tuples as argument lists to `check[]` (so half of `check[]` is superfluous, since we are only passing in lists of single digits).  The result is nested several layers deep and ignoring the 5 outermost layers leaves `{True/False, number}` pairs.  Keeping only those that `check[]` returned `True`, report all their number members.

There are, of course, a number of abbreviations and shortcuts that can be used on this code, but it took about as long to cut-paste-edit as it did to run, so probably wasteful to optimize further.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a software solution written in the c language using (obscure?) bit-wise logic checking if a number fulfills the criterion or not.

```
int check_number(int a){
  int l = a, mask = 0;
  for(;l;l/=10) {
    mask |= (1<<(l%10));
    mask |= (!(mask%2)) && (a%(l%10) != 0);}
  return (__builtin_popcount(mask)==6) && (!(mask%2));
}
```

The loop runs over each decimal digit by doing a sequence of dividing (/) by 10 and calculating the remainder (%). As you can see for book-keeping we revisit the bit field representation and population count operation in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1733753/mathematically-representing-combinations-with-integers-uniquely), but in this solution each logical value means that one digit is present AND divides our number. We could save a line if we were to find a cleverer way to avoid division by 0.

The result conforms with @Eric Tower s solution for at least smallest and largest numbers (123648 and 984312). I haven't bothered to check all of them.

Answer (score 0):

The highest match is 984312

I wrote a quick Python3 script to find all the matches:

```
for number in range(100000, 1000000):
    string = str(number)
    digits = []
    unique = True

    for ch in string:
        if ch in digits:
            unique = False
            break
        else:
            digits.append(ch)

    if not unique: # If the digits are not unique, move to the next iteration
        continue

    if all([False if digit == '0' else number % int(digit) == 0 for digit in str(number)]):
        # Number divides perfectly with every digit
        print(number)
```

This code will print every working number, each to a new line.

Answer (score -1):

The LCM of $1,2,3,4,5$ is $60$.

$$\frac{134520}{60} = 2242$$

Comment: I'm not sure if $134520$ is divisible by $0$.

Comment: @Kenny True....